# How to convert zend_db_table_rowset object to javascript array

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

how to convert zend_db_table_rowset object to javascript array

```
$db=new Application_Model_DbTable_Books();
        $result=$db->showBooks();
```

showBooks:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Books extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'books';
    protected $_primary = 'id';
    public function showBooks(){
            return $this->fetchAll();


}
```

}
I want to convert the result set in to something liket this:

```
  var aDataSet = [
                ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
                ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
                ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
                ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A']];
```

Comment: Where's the catch? Just `foreach` over the rowset, no?

Answer (score 1):

JSON fits bettew for such operations

Inside controller

```
$db=new Application_Model_DbTable_Books();
$result=$db->showBooks();    
$this->view->booksJson = Zend_Json::encode($result);
```

Inside view script

```
var aDataSet = JSON.parse(<?php echo $this->booksJson;?>);
```